# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid value for property <map>: [object Object]

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting below error when I am trying to call infoBox.open method in my page.

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid value for property : [object Object]**

The following is the code which I am using.

```
        var myInfoOptions = {                        
                content: 'Test'//$extradiv.html()
                , closeBoxMargin: "12px 2px 2px 2px"
                , closeBoxURL: '/Images/infowindow-close.gif'
                };

                var ib = new InfoBox(myInfoOptions);
                var info_Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(e.latLng.lat(), e.latLng.lng())
                });
                info_Marker.setMap(null);
                ib.open(map, info_Marker);
```

I have declared Map object globally and binding the data as below.

```
   var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

Hoping for quick response.

Thanks,
**Kalyan Basa**

Comment: in which line throws the error?. Second try to add the event handler with the listener

Comment: Why are you doing this: "info_Marker.setMap(null);"?  Seems like that would be a problem. Why not "info_Marker.setMap(map);"?

Comment: Jorge - I am getting error on this line  **"ib.open(map, info_Marker);"** <br/> geocodezip - I am using setMap(null) because I don't want to display marker on the map.

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/xCSuk/9/. Not sure what your issue is, a link to your map or a working demo of the problem would be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

1. you don't declare the variable "map" inside the window's scope
2. somewhere inside the document is an element with the **ID** "map" or a form, image, anchor etc. with the **name** "map"

What happens: IE

Here is the problem: When you don't declare the variable before the element is parsed, you cannot overwrite the reference to the element.

A demo for better understanding:

**Attempt#1:**

```
<input id="foo" type="button" value="click me to see foo's type-property" onclick="fx()">    
<script>
function fx()
{
   alert(foo.type);
}

window.onload=function()
{
   foo={type:'this is the type-property of the foo-variable'};
}
</script>
```

...the input#foo is parsed before the variable is created. The attempt to create the variable foo will fail in IE, because there already exists the reference to the input#foo accessible in global scope. The alert will return "button", the type of the input#foo
[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/kA9nb/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/kA9nb/)

**Attempt #2:**

```
<script>
var foo;

function fx()
{
   alert(foo.type);
}

window.onload=function()
{
   foo={type:'this is the type-property of the foo-variable'};
}
</script>
<input id="foo" type="button" value="click me to see foo's type-property" onclick="fx()">
```

As you can see, the variable foo is declared in global scope, before the input#foo is parsed.
IE now will not create the global reference to input#foo and everything works as expected:
http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/88QV8/

So the solution: **declare the variable "map" inside the global scope.**